# Directly controlling an AC load with a power phototriac

Tags: power, ac, mains

Searching for a phototriac to use in an AC dimmer circuit, I've come around this power phototriac -- [VO2223A](http://www.vishay.com/docs/81924/vo2223a.pdf).

With the load current of 1A, it looks like it could replace the traditional optocoupler-triac combo (IC1, T1):

[image]

Would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it will work, that's the reason why they produce it. You have to keep the current in the margins of specified rated current. This is also why the combo, as you named it IC + Triac exist, for larger current.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work.  You can see in the test circuits in Vishay's datasheet that the component is intended to handle both the optical isolation and power switching.

These parts are essentially SSRs.